# Media query not working in iOS 10

Tags: ios, css, safari, media-queries, ios10

I have the following media query:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link media="only screen and (max-height: 899px)" href="/ClientFiles/Demo/szxkLR.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link media="only screen and (min-height: 900px)" href="/ClientFiles/Demo/szxk.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

It doesn't work on iOS 10.0.3 with mobile Safari 10.0 and a resolution of 375 x 648. Is there anything in there that could be causing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```